# Working remotely from Germany for a US-based company?

Tags: germany, digital-nomads

I'm a US citizen, and from my understanding, I can visit Germany for no more than 90 days visa-free. I work for a US-based company, and I can work remotely, and I want to see if it's feasible for me to work remotely from Germany for more than 90 days up to 5 months.

Is this possible, and if so, what kind of permit and/or visa do I need for this?

Comment: You can indeed *visit* Germany for up to 90 days/180 but that doesn’t mean you can work remotely as a tourist. Germany has its own special freelance visa but that doesn’t appear suitable for what you’re looking for https://expertvagabond.com/digital-nomad-work-visas/

Comment: @Traveller yeah, I guess most digital nomads that go there just do it on the down low